# Impedindo reenvio de dados ao atualizar página (F5) em ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Galera, estou com o seguinte problema:

Tenho uma aplicação web feita com ASP.NET e C#.

Nesta aplicação eu tenho um sistema simples de cadastro de itens.

Depois que eu cadastro um item na aplicação, se eu mandar atualizar a página do browser (apertar f5), o browser abre um pop up pedindo para reenviar o formulário, consequentemente ele gera uma duplicata no banco.

Esse é o trecho do código onde eu faço o cadastro no banco:

```
PgSqlConnection Myconn = new PgSqlConnection(connectionString);
        query = "INSERT INTO banco(a,b,c,d,e,f) VALUES (" + a + "," + b.SelectedValue + "," + c + "," + d + "," + e +"," + f.SelectedValue + ")";
        PgSqlCommand Command = new PgSqlCommand(query, Myconn);
        Myconn.Open();
        try
        {
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (PgSqlException ex)
        {
            String myscript = "alert('Não foi possível executar esta ação')";
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myscript", myscript, true);
        }
```

Como posso impedir isso?

Para facilitar futuras pesquisas, segue abaixo o trecho do código com a solução do problema:

```
    PgSqlConnection Myconn = new PgSqlConnection(connectionString);
    query = "INSERT INTO banco(a,b,c,d,e,f) VALUES (" + a + "," + b.SelectedValue + "," + c + "," + d + "," + e +"," + f.SelectedValue + ")";
    PgSqlCommand Command = new PgSqlCommand(query, Myconn);
    Myconn.Open();
    try
    {
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery();            
        Response.Redirect("estearquivo.aspx"); //isto soluciona o problema
    }
    catch (PgSqlException ex)
    {
        String myscript = "alert('Não foi possível executar esta ação')";
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "myscript", myscript, true);
    }
```

Comment: Você tem como mostrar o código dessa inserção, incluindo o evento que chama esta inserção?

Comment: Você está verificando se é um *Postback*?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Já respondi uma pergunta equivalente em PHP, mas o mesmo vale para qualquer outra linguagem pois o que está em questão é uma requisição em HTTP. Vamos lá:

Quando você faz um POST em um formulário, é incorreto que você gere a listagem (ou uma mensagem de confirmação, ou qualquer outra coisa) na resposta desse POST. O certo é que você *redirecione* o usuário para outra página, gerando um GET logo depois desse POST.

Com isso, um F5 causaria um GET na página seguinte e não um POST, impedindo que o formulário seja postado novamente.

Comment: Atualizei o post com um trecho do meu código, pode mostrar como poderia alterar para corrigir esse problema?

Comment: Pelo que me parece, você renderiza o template de retorno mais ou menos no mesmo trecho em que você tenta fazer a inserção no seu banco de dados. O que você precisa retornar é um redirect 301 para outra página, ao invés de renderizar um template.

Comment: @RodrigoRigotti O redirect 301 seria inapropriado neste caso. Um código mais adequado seria o 303. **Explicação**: O 301 indica um redirecionamento permanente, a rigor, o navegador não acessaria este endereço novamente, mas sim o seguinte. Já o 303 indica que o conteúdo está em outro local, mas o primeiro endereço não pode ser suprimido. **Fonte**: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Answer (score 4):

Esse é um problema simples: ao dar F5, sendo que a última ação foi um POST, o browser reenvia o POST. Como o @Rodrigo Rigotti disse você pode no primeiro POST direcionar com um 301 para outra página, por exemplo mandar para a página de lista de itens cadastrados.

O código que você postou em sua pergunta é só a execução da inserção dos dados, não é nela que você precisa alterar, e sim no controle de requisições HTTP. Se você quiser redirecionar para outra página apôs inserir os dados use o [Response Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Response.Redirect("OutraPagina.aspx", false);
```

Há um exemplo detalhado [neste link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6413/Stop-Refresh-after-Submitting-your-Request).

Ou você pode guardar na [viewstate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx) da sua página o tipo de ação do usuário e verificar a ação antes de salvar os dados. Veja esse [outro link com um exemplo detalhado](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28099/Refresh-Page-Issue-in-ASP-Net).

Espero que tenha ajudado.